How do I determine the right branch of logarithm to determine the path integral of $f(z)= \frac{1}{z}$?
I want to calculate the integral of $f(z)= \frac{1}{z}$ over the path:
$$\alpha : [0,4] \to \mathbb{C}, \alpha (t) =   
 \begin{cases} 
   1+t(i-1) & t \in [0,1] \\ 
   2i+t(-i-1)+1 & t \in [1,2] \\ 
   2i+t(-i+1)-3 & t \in [2,3] \\ 
   -4i+t(i+1)-3 & t \in [3,4] \\ 
\end{cases}.$$
and I get:
\begin{align}
&\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \left(\int_{0}^{1} \frac{i-1}{1+t(i-1)} \ dt + \int_{1}^{2} \frac{-i-1}{2i+1+t(-i-1)} \ dt + \int_{2}^{3} \frac{-i+1}{2i-3+t(-i+1)} \ dt + \int_{3}^{4} \frac{i+1}{-4i-3+t(i+1)} \ dt \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2 \pi i}  \left(\log(1+t(i-1))|_0^1  + \log(2i+t(-i-1)+1)|_1^2 + \log(2i+t(-i+1)-3)|_2^3 + \log(-4i+t(i+1)-3)|_3^4\right) \\
&= \log(i) - \log(1) + \log(-1) - \log(i) + \log(-i) - \log(-1) + \log(1) - \log(-i)
\end{align}
First I tried to use the principal branch of the logarithm, but then the integral would be $0$, but the solution should be
$2 \pi i$. The reason for that is, $\log(z)$ is discontinuous in $(- \infty,0]$ for the principal branch.
Therefore I have to choose a different branch of the logarithm, where $\log(z)$ is continuous in $z=-1$. But unfortunately I don't know how to find the right branch and how to calculate this path-integral.

Note that there is no branch cut that avoids the whole image of $\alpha$, so you simply cannot use a single primitive to evaluate the path integral. Break up $\alpha$ into two paths and use different branches (and branch cuts) for each.

oh sry, i corrected it. I meant it is uncontinuous in $(-\infty,0]$ for the principle branch.

Equivalently, $\alpha(t)=i^{\lfloor t\rfloor}(1+(i-1){t})$.

Since the path is started and ended at $(1,0)=1+0i$, run your branch through that point. You are basically starting just on one side of the branch and ending just on the other, so you don't actually cross the branch.
You should get $2\pi i$.

Do I understand correctly that you suggest using something like $\int_\alpha = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\alpha|[\epsilon, 4 - \epsilon]}$?

Yes, this is what you are really doing. For positive $\epsilon$ you have a gap into which to "thread the needle" with the branch cut. The integral as a function of $\epsilon$ is fairly complicated, but setting all $\epsilon\to0$ gets rid of all the complicated stuff and you emerge with $2\pi i$.
